# How to call the variable declared in user defined function in python

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, nameerror

Whenever I define any function in python with variables, I am not able to call or print the values of variable declared in the function, and hence am unable to use that variable in subsequent lines of code.
It'd be really helpful if I could know that where am I wrong in using it.

For example, the following lines of code of creating a list of 500 numbers:
it gives error : NameError: name 'r1' is not defined

```
def createlist(r1):
    for n in range(1,500):
        return np.arange(r1, r1+n, 1)
    r1 = 1
    print(createlist(r1))
```

Comment: This code is probably not what you're actually running - the function will return during the first iteration of the `for` loop and will never reach the final two lines, assuming you do call the function from somewhere.

Comment: Can you please help as in what should i do then? So that after all iterations then my function yields the last tow line outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not work for what you want.

Instead try this code.

```
import numpy as np
def createlist(r1):
    for n in range(1,500):
        print(np.arange(r1, r1+n, 1))
r1 = 1
#print(createlist(r1))
createlist(r1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of indentation.

You are declaring `r1` in your function. it gives you error because the `print(createlist(r1))` can not see the `r1`. so the solution is :

```
import numpy as np
def createlist(r1):
    for n in range(1,500):
        return np.arange(r1, r1+n, 1)
r1 = 1
print(createlist(r1))
```

Hope it helps you <3

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to correctly indent your code and also you want to return the result of each iteration, you can try this

```
import numpy as np


def createlist(r1):
    op = []
    for n in range(1, 500):
        op.append(list(np.arange(r1, r1 + n, 1)))   # op is storing the list generated in each iteration
    return op   # now you can return op, a list which contains results from the loop


r1 = 1
print(createlist(r1))
```

p.s. Please include more explanation of what you want to do.